# hiding element when clicked

Tags: jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#cover img").click(function(event)
        {
            var selected_script = $(this).attr('id');

            //alert(selected_script);
        //alert('#run_'+selected_script);

            $('#run_'+selected_script).hide();
        });
    });

<div>
    <img id="run_0" src="play.png" />
</div>
```

Code above doesn't hide image when clicked. When I alert I get correct value for the ID.

What am I missing?

thanks

Comment: You want to hide the same image as you click on?

Comment: What are you trying to hide? Could you show related html? According you code you should have an element with id = `run_run_0`

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I should have ben like this : `$('#'+selected_script).hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#cover img").click(function(e)
        {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });

<div id='cover'>
    <img id="run_0" src="play.png" />
</div>
```

1. Your 'selected_script' var would contain the id. Why again prepend "run" before?
2. You only want the img in the #cover id to have the onclick. Your div (or a parent element) should have the 'cover' id.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't trying to hide it in the code above, just do a simple `.hide()`

```
$("#cover img").on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).hide();

    // If you want to know why your above code isn't working, it is because you have:
    // $('#run_'+selected_script).hide();
    // selected_script already has the entire ID of run_0, etc
    // so this is outputting $('#run_run_0').hide(); why it doesn't work

    $('#' + selected_script).hide(); // this outputs $('#run_0').hide(), and will work!
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uXR5S/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#cover img").click(function(event)
        {    
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly hide it by

```
$(this).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's why your code isn't working: http://jsfiddle.net/prsjohnny/wp5Bs/

But (in case you are new to jQuery) you already have the element you are looking for, so why look for it again?

This is much more efficient.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#cover img").click(function(event)
    {
        // just use $(this) instead of $('#'+selected_script) and 
        // having jquery traverse the DOM again looking for it.
        $(this).hide();
    });
});​
```